# Record Very Low Sound

Tags: recording, sound

I want to record very low sound. This sound can be heard by ear, so it is in the range of 20 Hz to 20,000 Hz , but i think it is more between 20 hz to 200 hz .

The sound that i want to record is broadcasted , so it is broadcasted in plain air , like when you are sitting in a coffee shop , so you can hear it and you can hear other people voices  , what i want is to be ableto record this sound that is broadcasted in plain over a very low frequency .

i don't think that we can use a contact mic , so i was wondering what kind of microphone you think is capable of recording this voice .

Thank you for your help and for recommending a mic that i can buy , and that can do this . it is appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A condenser or dynamic (better for loud sounds) will pick this up generally you want a microphone with a frequency response tailored for recording kick drums, bass cabinets, and other bass instruments such as:
AKG D112, Shure Beta 52A, Audix D6

Most synths can produce this frequency easily if you want a clean sound without the hassle. You will have more issues playing a 20Hz wave that people can hear in public without large speakers.

"Because of their increased wavelength (nearly 20 meters at 20 Hz), achieving high output at low frequencies usually requires large drivers (subwoofers). Headphones or earbuds, have less trouble playing back those low frequencies despite their small size: by sealing your ear canal, they create a volume that acts as a pressure chamber. "[link](https://www.audiocheck.net/audiotests_frequencychecklow.php)

Answer (score 0):

You will require a condensor microphone with adequate wind protection. You will need to use something like a Rycote blimp. This will protect the mic against wind effects which will appear at similar frequencies to the ones you are looking to record.

Comment: so do you believe that this : https://www.mytek.tn/microphone-gamer/17831-microphone-numerique-et-multidirectionnel-razer-.html or this https://www.musicplus.tn/live-sound/microphones/akg-perception-820-micro-tube-statique-de-studio.html will work ?

Comment: no. these are studio mics, not suited for the purpose you have described. Check out the Rycote wind protection - you will see the sort of mics that are suited.

Comment: okay , thank you so much , i searched and wasn't able to find anything , could you please provide a direct link for the microphone that you are suggesting , it would be truly appreciated  . Thank You So Much